# django set session variable till end of day

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, session-variables

I need to set a session variable that expires at the end of each day.

I know I can set a session variable like this:

```
request.session['my_variable'] = 'foo'
```

How can I then have this expire at the end of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an entire session to expire at the end of the day with

```
request.session.set_expiry(seconds_until_end_of_day)
```

or you can set a default expiration for all session cookies in your app with the setting

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE
```

again in seconds. If you absolutely need to set a specific cookie to have a special expiration then you may have to look into the [session backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-engine).

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, you don't want to expire the whole session. So there is a way to expire only the one variable - save the variable in the dictionary with the expiration time.

```
def set_expirable_var(session, var_name, value, expire_at):
    session[var_name] = {'value': value, 'expire_at': expire_at.timestamp()}
```

Set the variable using this function:

```
expire_at = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.max.time())
set_expirable_var(request.session, expire_at)
```

And before you get the value you should check whether the variable is not expired.

```
def get_expirable_var(session, var_name, default=None):
    var = default
    if var_name in session:  
        my_variable_dict = session.get(var_name, {})
        if my_variable_dict.get('expire_at', 0) > datetime.datetime.now().timestamp():
            myvar = my_variable_dict.get('value')
    else:
        del session[var_name]
    return var
```

Comment: This actually answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44163825/171993).  Instead of storing the data in the session itself, it can be stored in the cache and linked to the session ID.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set(f'{request.session.session_key}_my_variable', value, seconds_until_end_of_day)
```

The above answers will work for small amounts of data, but if the data is large, one would actually want it to be removed after expiry.  The cache will take care of that.

Another limitation of the above answers is that data stored in the session needs to be JSON serializable, but any data can be stored in the cache (such as a byte array).

Comment: Great answer, solved my problem exactly for 0 cost. Code is beautiful. Life is beautiful. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Like another reply here above, but a little bit better and without errors (I hope).
In this way you can have only one variable expiring after 5 minutes:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def set_expirable_var(session, var_name, value, expire_at):
    session[var_name] = {'value': value, 'expire_at': expire_at.timestamp()}

def get_expirable_var(session, var_name, default=None):
    var = default
    if var_name in session:
        my_variable_dict = session.get(var_name, {})
        if my_variable_dict.get('expire_at', 0) > datetime.now().timestamp():
            var = my_variable_dict.get('value')
        else:
            del session[var_name]
    return var
```

When you have to read and or/save the variable result you can use:

```
sum = get_expirable_var(request.session, 'sum', None)
if sum is None:
    sum = 4 + 5
    expire_at = datetime.today() + timedelta(minutes=5)
    set_expirable_var(request.session, 'sum', sum, expire_at)
```