# Expiring specific session variable in Django

Tags: django, django-sessions

It's easy to expire the request.session dictionary via `request.session.set_expiry(seconds_until_end_of_day)` or via `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`.

But how do I set the expiry of a **specific** session variable? E.g. I've alloted an unauth user a `temp_id`. I need this `temp_id` to cease to exist in 30 mins. What's the best, most performant way to achieve that?

Comment: I think that [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/) is the best place to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about putting it in the cache instead

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('{0}_temp_id'.format(request.session.session_key, value, timeout
```

This is uniquely associated with the user and automatically expires. No need for complicated middleware